# Apex REST: query parameters

Tags: apexrest

I have a rest endpoint defined as:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/invoice_data')
global with sharing class Service_Invoices {
    @HttpGet
    global static void findAttachementForInvoice(){
        String invoiceId = RestContext.request.params.get('invoice_id');
        doSomethingWithInvoiceId(invoiceId);
    }
}
```

When I do a get on `/invoice_data` this works fine (i.e. the method is reached). I then proceed to try and query the url with a query parameter a la [this tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST#Using_GET_and_DELETE), using a query of `/invoice_data?invoice_id=potato`. However, I'm getting an error:

```
[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"Could not find a match for URL"}]
```

I've tried to change the `urlMaping` to `/invoice_data/*` as that is how it is defined in the tutorial, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling Web service properly. This is how your URL should be:

```
/services/apexrest/invoice_data/<Record ID>
```

And access record Id using following code:

```
RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
// grab the caseId from the end of the URL
String recordId = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Go through this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_webservices)

Comment: The tutorial uses the `services/apexrest/endpoint_name?param_name=param_value` method of passing query parameters. Is that method no longer supported?

Comment: @WiseTree It is supported. Just go to workbench-> Rest Explorer and enter above endpoint with appropriate `Id`, you'll get response.

Answer (score 2):

Using ***request.params*** query parameters can be accessed.

While using query parameters URL will look like this:
/services/apexrest/invoice_data/?recordid=